# pdf not getting downloaded in pre-lollipop devices using download manager

Tags: android, pdf, android-download-manager

I am trying to download pdf using `DownloadManager`.

I am passing parameter in link and from server pdf file generated and downloaded into device. so my download link would be some what like this

> `http://example.com/gen.php?data={......}`

**My Code :**

```
final Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(fromUrl));
request.setMimeType("application/pdf");
request.setNotificationVisibility(Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(path, "ELALA_MANIFEST_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".pdf");

final DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
try {
    try {
        dm.enqueue(request);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        request.setNotificationVisibility(Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
        Log.e("Error", e.toString());
        dm.enqueue(request);
    }

}
// if the download manager app has been disabled on the device
catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    openAppSettings(context,
            AdvancedWebView.PACKAGE_NAME_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER);
}
```

This **works fine in device with api level 21 (lollipop) and above**. but in lower version pdf not getting downloaded. and notification pops like,

> ```
> <untitled> download unsuccessful
> ```

I know it something has to do with `setMimeType`, but  don't know what.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Other file types work fine on the pre-lollipop of yours?

Comment: @KamranAhmed yes...

Comment: Can you fetch the DownloadManager database with `adb root && adb pull /data/data/com.android.providers.downloads/databases/downloads.db .`?

Comment: i don't know how to fatch. can you please explain it?

Comment: Try downloading a PDF file on your pre-lollipop device, once it fails, connect it to PC and run `adb root && adb pull /data/data/com.android.providers.downloads/databases/downloa‌​ds.db .` in your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

When You get `<untitled> download unsuccessful`, usually it means Your url was not correct or empty or null. So first of all please be sure url is OK.

Look at my small example with DownloadManager which runs in 4.4 (pre-lolipop).

```
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DownloadManager dm;
    private String url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        url = "https://collegereadiness.collegeboard.org/pdf/psat-nmsqt-practice-test-1.pdf";

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(url)) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("url cannot be empty or null");
                }

                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

                if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {
                    String uriString = v.getContext().getExternalFilesDir(null) + "";
                    File file = new File(uriString, Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment());
                    Uri destinationUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    request.setDestinationUri(destinationUri);
                    dm.enqueue(request);
                }
            }
        });

        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive() returned: " + action);
                // TODO: 2016-10-12  
            } else if (DownloadManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED.equals(action)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive() returned: " + action);
                // TODO: 2016-10-12  
            }
        }
    };

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    //...

    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state);
    }

    public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state);
    }
}
```

It uses permissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

It is important to handle all conditions. Also try use app directory instead messing around i.e on Your sd card. This example saves downloaded files in 
`/sdcard/Android/data/{your app package name}/files/`. Previously I check if I have mounted sdcard and if I can write on directory.

Sample:

[image]

---

Okay, here is my sample with resolving filename if header has "Content-Disposition` field. You said it is on YOur server, so You will be able do it :)

```
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DownloadManager dm;
    private String url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        url = "http://dl1.shatelland.com/files/07610a8d-a73f-45bb-8868-6fd33299bda7/6e33639f-0ce0-43ef-86e4-43492db1be86";

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        downloadFileInTask(v.getContext(), url);
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });

        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    }

    private void downloadFileInTask(Context v, String url) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(this.url)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("url cannot be empty or null");
        }

        /*when redirecting from hashed url and found headerField "Content-Disposition"*/
        String resolvedFile = resolveFile(url, "unknown_file");

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

        if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {
            File file = new File(v.getExternalFilesDir(null), resolvedFile);
            Uri destinationUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            request.setDestinationUri(destinationUri);
            dm.enqueue(request);
        }
    }

    private String resolveFile(String url, String defaultFileName) {
        String filename = defaultFileName;

        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        try {
            con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            con.connect();

            String contentDisposition = con.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(contentDisposition)) {
                String[] splittedCD = contentDisposition.split(";");
                for (int i = 0; i < splittedCD.length; i++) {
                    if (splittedCD[i].trim().startsWith("filename=")) {
                        filename = splittedCD[i].replaceFirst("filename=", "").trim();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            con.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return filename;
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive() returned: " + action);
                // TODO: 2016-10-12  
            } else if (DownloadManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED.equals(action)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive() returned: " + action);
                // TODO: 2016-10-12  
            }
        }
    };

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    //...

    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state);
    }

    public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. but i'm my case pdf is not saved somewhere on server. it is generated from parameters i pass. so my download link would be some what like this `http://example.com/gen.php?data={......}`

Comment: OK, thank You, I will try edit my answer. Please be more specific when creating question. :)

Comment: wait.. i'll be back with sample.